# Change radius for proportional editing

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, shortcut, proportional-editing

When proportional editing is enabled in edit mode, then if you select and drag a point, nearby points will also move with it. The effect has a certain radius. How can you set this radius?

According to [the documentation I found](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?#proportional-editing), you can set it using the scroll wheel or <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>. I tried those, but <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> seem to do nothing, and the scroll wheel instead zooms. What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You must press <kbd>PgUp</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd> or use the scroll wheel *during* a transform action such as *Translate* (<kbd>G</kbd>), *Rotate* (<kbd>R</kbd>), or *Scale* (<kbd>S</kbd>).

During a transform operation, you can see the proportional size visualized as as a circle around the *[Pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html?#pivot-point)* and you can see the actual proportional size value displayed in the *Header*:

[image]

In the *Redo panel* located at the bottom of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view) or found by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, there is a slider to adjust the Proportional size. **Note that this only applies immediately *after* a transform operation**.

Comment: also you only see the ring when you are in the transform mode.

Comment: For anyone working out and about on a Mac laptop (so trackpad - no mouse), you can adjust the sphere of influence using **fn** + **Page Up** / **Page Down**.

Comment: and further to GLCoder's perfectly correct advice, if you're using a Mac wireless keyboard + wacom tablet, you can assign buttons on the tablet to fn+Page Up/Page Down (a key combination almost impossible for me to achieve on the wireless keyboard, so far apart as they are)

Comment: For macbook pro trackpad with mouse gestures on, just slide two fingers up or down like you would do for scrolling... saves having to use multiple key strokes.

Comment: Followed this answer. Enabled **Proportional Editing Mode**, selected vertices in **Edit Mode**, began vertex transformation and used mouse scroll while doing so. I can see the **Proportional Size** parameter changing, but no white circle indicating radius ever appears. Not on minimum radius, nor on maximum radius or anywhere inbetween.

Comment: @Mär Curious, just tested in 2.83 and it's there for me.. Can you confirm with 2.83 and factory settings as well?

Comment: @gandalf3 I am on version 2.79, the application is on factory settings. The behavior stopped occuring after the application was relaunched - now it behaves as expected following the same exact steps described above.

Comment: @Mär Glad it's working!

Answer (score 3):

For fine tuning you should use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

For perfect sphere (I was seeking!) Global size (key it in manually) should match Proportional size.

Answer (score 0):

Select one ore multiple vertex points and scroll with your mouse wheel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/40510)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos explain how this does not answer the question. You can use the mousewheel to change the radius, it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It does a poor job at explaining *when* to use the mouse wheel (during transforms), which was the initial difficulty of the poster. It also adds nothing new to gandalf's answer which already covers it well.This question is also quite old, from 2014, try answering a newer one ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer on how to adjust the proportional size has already been given. I just wanted to add that you can see whether <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDown</kbd> / <kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> are working at the top of the window.

In my case, the circle was too large compared to the objects so I couldn't see it getting smaller for quite awhile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should take care of "**during a transform operation**". When you press <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>  to transform the mesh , and at the same time scroll the <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> , it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `page up/dn` worked after I began to move the vertices. If I only selected them and wasn't "during a transform operation" then the cursor scaling didnt work.