# Soft Select / Proportional Editing tool White circle guide disappeared

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I am not sure when it happened, but I went to do proportional editing and the guide-circle that indicates how large an area is being affected, had disappeared.  At first i though it was perhaps very large suddenly but I scrolled out and it was not there.  When I select one vertex with soft select enabled it will just move the whole mesh, now.   Did I accidentally click the wrong thing, or could this be a glitch because my hard drive is in the red zone (getting full) ?  I restarted my PC but the problem remained.  Could i solve the problem by reinstalling Blender?

I opened another smaller file and the soft select circle is there!  So this problem only applies to this one project file.

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: When Proportional Editing is active look in the 3D View header and find there option *Proprortional Size* (the last one); you might want to include that info into the screenshot. It still seems the size of PE is too high.

Comment: Holy moly... that number was up in the millions.  Thanks for the tip.  I had to scroll it down for a very long time before it reached a reasonable size.  I never would have known just HOW huge the circle had become without looking at that number.  I wonder how it got so big?

Comment: In the millions ? I'm not sure how to get it up there. If you just scroll the wheel / use `PgUp` & `PgDown` it will stop at 1000. You can multiply it by any value in `F6` panel (after executing operator with any option), but this value won't be saved for the next operation. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing

Comment: Btw, in twist mode (CTRL - t) the circle size is NOT shown. To see if this number is to high, pick a vertex type G and look at the header as suggested by Mr Zak. After "scrolling" the size down, twists works nicely again.