# How to achieve a sharp tip/edge for a blade?

Tags: mesh

I would like to make one edge sharp, and for the tip to be sharp as well. I've considered using the bevel tool, merging vertices, or just scaling things down to almost no distance. What would be the best way to make a sharp edge/tip?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  It's important to keep ***Quad*** topology with practically everything you model.  This will keep you from hating life when you're 3/4 of the way through your model.

Here's a simple method to get you started:

1.) Create a plane and subdivide it.  Use ***Proportional Editing*** to curve your blade:

[image]

---

2.) Add a ***Mirror Modifier*** to the plane and select *"Merge"* and *"Clipping"* options.

[image]

---

3.) <kbd>Alt</kbd> select the blade edge and ***Translate*** them toward the center of the ***mirror***.  Then, using ***Proportional Editing***, *Scale* in the spine toward the tip.

[image]

---

4.) <kbd>Alt</kbd> select the Spine edge and ***Extrude*** it toward the center of the ***mirror***.

[image]

---

5.) ***Apply*** the ***Mirror Modifier*** at this point and then create a quad out of the remaining vertices of the tip.

[image]

---

6.) <kbd>Alt</kbd> select the blade and the two edges of the spine (if you want, the two main ridges that run down the blade also) and create creases by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, then press <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  I have given the blade a ***Subdivision Modifier*** also:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @StefanG. You're very welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: I've encountered a few issues. I've created the plane, haven't extruded it (as that is not mentioned) and have attempted to mirror it. No matter which axis I select, there does not seem to be another plane to clip it against. UPDATE: I had to apply the location, which is what fixed it (CTR + A -> Location), but now, my issue is with proportional editing. It moves a few vertices awkwardly, rather than the smooth transition you have. What settings did you use/do you recommend?

Comment: Update #2: Step 3 is unclear. I move the blade edge towards the centre but that creates a mysterious ghost vertex. Then, regardless of the subdivision modifier, the tip of the blade looks odd, as if it is pinched (most likely due to the ghost vertex). http://i.imgur.com/ADdKV7Q.png ; http://i.imgur.com/0MjIQnT.png

Comment: @StefanG. - It is critical that you keep tris and ngons out of your mesh.  I see both in the tip of your model.  Delete that stray vertex **and** the one above it and rebuild those faces.  Also, select the edge in the middle of the tip of the spine and **Dissolve** it to make those two tris a quad.  Look closely at the geometry in the gif on step 5 and try to duplicate that in your mesh.

Comment: @StefanG. - as far as Proportional Editing, there is virtually no end to the threads on this forum dedicated to that subject.  I believe I used **Sharp** as the falloff type.  See this also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing

Comment: @StefanG. - Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Update #3: Yes. I've deleted the ghost vertex, ensured I only had quads, scaled everything in to have a more appealing look, and then added loop cuts for the indentation on the outside of the blade. http://i.imgur.com/iKWLDta.png http://i.imgur.com/3TYD0Aa.png

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whatever you feel is best.
You can scale it down a lot. You can merge it and have less geometry.(Preferred)
I'm not sure what exactly your question is.