# How to change radius for proportional editing using industry compatible keyboard mapping (v3.0)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, shortcut, proportional-editing

How do you change the [influence](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?highlight=proportional%20editing#influence) when using proportional editing in Blender **using industry compatible shortcuts**?

What I've Tried:

- Reading similar question here [this article](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing), but with the `industry compatible` shortcuts.
- Looking up keymaps in blender preferences, but I must be using the wrong search term. Tried `radius` and `influence`.
- Examining their [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?highlight=proportional%20editing#influence) on the subject

Comment: use 'B' to enable/disable and while dragging use PgUp/PgDn or mouse wheel

Answer (score 1):

**The mappings are the same**. Mouse <kbd>Wheel Up</kbd>/<kbd>Wheel Down</kbd> or <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> after hitting <kbd>B</kbd> to enable proportional editing.

Make sure you are actively holding down the left mouse button while scrolling. More [details about that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7154/143390)..

You can confirm the keymap by going to *Edit > Preferences > Transform Modal Map > Increase Proportional Influence*.

[image: Keyboard Mappings for Influence]

Works Cited: [developer issue T87869](https://developer.blender.org/T87869), [@alambre's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/32601/alambre) comment.