# Any way to invert the proportional editing radius controls?

Tags: customization

It feels super backwards to me as is - is there any way to invert the proportional editing radius controls?

Comment: How do you exactly want it inverted...?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255660/how-to-change-radius-for-proportional-editing-using-industry-compatible-keyboard

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ahaha, that makes sense... I was completely confused thinking about something else :D