# change radius in proportional editing without mouse wheel

Tags: proportional-editing, keymap

I am working with Wacom Cintique and its quite annoying to change from the pen to the mouse in order to change the radius. [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing) I found the keys "page up" and "down which" would be handy. But it doesn't work for me for some reason. It doesn't change the radius but moves the mesh instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Page uP and Down works as expected for me.