# Changing Radius size of Proportional Editing (PGUp/Down not working, no wheel)

Tags: modeling, proportional-editing

I'm currently using blender 3.5.0, I work with a Asus laptop and my huion display tablet. Emulate numpad and 3 button mouse are both on.

I've been following Eve Sculpt's youtube room tutorials and hit a bit of a snag. From some searching, you're supposed to be able to use a scroll wheel or PG-Up/Down to change the size of the radius of Proportional Editing in edit mode. My PG buttons do work for everything else such as adding more loop cuts and I have added Wheel Forward/Backward keys to my tablet buttons, but they do not work on changing the size of the radius. I have tried changing it on a brand new file to make sure I hadn't accidentally set it to something miniscule/massive, but no luck.

Is there anything else I could be missing to try and fix this problem?

Edit 1: I managed to acquire a mouse /w a wheel. I tried using the scroll wheel on a new file and that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem - I believe that one of the edit tools actually has to be ACTIVE at the time, for example by pressing the left-mouse button.   It's a tremendously awkward combination (mouse button plus pgup/pgdn) but it does work for me.    I found the other combination (mouse button plus mouse scroll) virtually impossible to use.

See also  [this answer.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing)